# How to add the Public group in Managed Package

Tags: apex, trigger, public-group

How to add the public group in managed package and how to get the notification when delete or renamed the group name.

Is there any possibilities in SFDC?

Comment: Lemon can you add some more details or a code snippet of what you already have ? There's some context missing to easily answer this.

Comment: i just provided the clear information kindly review and let me know the solution if any?

Answer (score -1):

Add following lines in Package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>*<members>
    <name>Group<name>
</types>
```